# Query Result based on prioritization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i need your help in this SQL server Query.

Query :
        Search by: 'AJ' .The result should be prioritized by Shortnames first then look in fullnames. No duplicates

Tbl Name

```
ID  Shortname       FullName    
1   AJ          Ajay Jangid
2   AM          Ajna mathew         
3   AJ          Ajay Jahangir
4   CG          Chiraj gupta



result:
ID  Shortname       FullName
1   AJ          Ajay Jangid
3   AJ          Ajay Jahangir
2   AM          Ajna mathew
```

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of matching are you trying to perform? i.e. is the shortname match always exact?

Answer (score 1):

you can use order by clause for sorting basis 2 columns as well..

Select ...Where...*Order by Shortname, fullname*

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        select distinct * from TabelName
        where FullName like 'AJ%'
        order by Shortname
```